# Keycloak with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, keycloak

I have a problem.
I have a project that consists of many services written on Spring boot framework, also they are all  using Keycloak. When keycloak is crashing and not available for example for 2-3 mins, and after time, when it becomes active and available my other services needs to be restarted. I think that not should be work like this. Services should reconnect automatically to Keycloak, but now they are not.

I am using Spring Boot 2.5.0, and Keycloak 14.0.0.

Any ideas, please!)

I have searched in google, and documentation, but nothing found.

Comment: Do you get any error message, stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using the default KeyCloak adapter for authentication?